# Get a variable from filename string in windows batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, forfiles

good day, i have a folder with 400 files and i want to print a "name" from the filenames
this is the structure
ej:

```
20201323223_vendo.perfil01_17872513294967257_1601950878_live.mp4
20201323223__vvcastrillon_12_17949951031375250_1601939874_live.mp4
2020323123_yessromero.g_17849208194340047_1601945592_live.mp4
2020323223_ziizii_08_17979840166310477_1601929868_live.mp4
```

and what i need is

```
vendo.perfil01
_vvcastrillon_12
yessromero.g
ziizii_08
```

Im try to loop in the files and separate whit the _ and extract the 2 and 3 token numeral conditioning but the result is wrong and missing variables

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
:loop
SET max=5000
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir "*_*_*.mp4" /A-D /B /S 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /L /V "\\outdir\\"') do (for /F "eol=| tokens=2,3 delims=_" %%J in ("%%~nI") do (SET "var="&for /f "delims=0123456789" %%a in ("%%K") do SET var=%%a
if defined var ( set nam=%%J_%%K ) else ( set nam=%%J )
)
echo/!nam!
)
timeout 10 > nul
goto loop
```

i think the answer is remove the first number before the _ then the string _xxxxxx_xxxxxxx_live.mp4 at the end but i dont know how read in reverse the tokens

tanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have got different numbers of `_`-separated items in your file names and even adjacent `_`, so using [`for /F`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) to split them into specific tokens with `delims=_` is not the best choice.

I would use a standard [`for`-loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) instead, which receives modified file names, namely with each `_` replaced by `" "` and enclosed within `""`, which leads to <kbd>SPACE</kbd>-separated partial name items. So:

> ```cmd
> 20201323223_vendo.perfil01_17872513294967257_1601950878_live.mp4
> ```

is changed to:

> ```cmd
> "20201323223" "vendo.perfil01" "17872513294967257" "1601950878" "live.mp4"
> ```

before looping. Within the loop implement an index counter and just append those items to a buffer whose index numbers lie within a certain range that depends on the total number of items.

Here is an example script that demonstrates what I mean:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_ROOT=%~dp0."           & rem // (full path to target directory)
set "_MASK=*_*_*_*_live.mp4" & rem // (pattern to match file names)
set "_FILT=^[0123456789][0123456789]*_..*_[0123456789][0123456789]*_[0123456789][0123456789]*_live\.mp4$"
                               rem // (additional `findstr` filter for file names)
set /A "_POS=1"              & rem /* (index of first `_`-separated item to extract;
                               rem     `0` is the first item, `-1` is the last) */
set /A "_NUM=-4"             & rem /* (number of `_`-separated items to extract;
                               rem     `-1` means all up to the last item) */

rem // Change into target directory:
pushd "%_ROOT%" && (
    rem // Loop through all matching non-hidden, non-system files:
    for /F "delims= eol=|" %%F in ('
        dir /B /A:-D-H-S "%_MASK%" ^| findstr /I /R /C:"%_FILT%"
    ') do (
        rem // Store current file name, initialise item index, counter and buffer:
        set "FILE=%%F" & set /A "IDX=-1, CNT=-1" & set "BUFF=_"
        rem // Toggle delayed expansion to avoid troubles with `!`:
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        rem // Count number of items and store one less:
        rem set "TEST=%FILE:_=" & set /A "CNT+=1" & set "TEST=%"
        for %%I in ("!FILE:_=" "!") do set /A "CNT+=1"
        rem // Determine item index position from given index and number:
        if !_POS! lss 0 (set /A "BEG=CNT+_POS+1") else set /A "BEG=_POS"
        if !_NUM! lss 0 (set /A "END=CNT+_NUM+1") else set /A "END=_POS+_NUM-1"
        rem // Transport numbers over `endlocal` barrier:
        for %%C in (!CNT!) do for %%B in (!BEG!) do for %%A in (!END!) do (
            rem // Loop through `_`-separated items of file name:
            for %%I in ("!FILE:_=" "!") do (
                rem // Store current item, increment item index:
                endlocal & set "ITEM=%%~I" & set /A "IDX+=1"
                setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                rem // Append current item to buffer if in range:
                if !IDX! geq %%B if !IDX! leq %%A (
                    rem // Transport buffer over `endlocal` barrier:
                    for /F "delims=" %%E in ("BUFF=!BUFF!_!ITEM!") do (
                        endlocal & set "%%E"
                        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                    )
                )
            )
        )
        rem // Return buffer:
        echo(!BUFF:~2!
        endlocal
    )
    rem // Return from target directory:
    popd
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

Comment: why the program dont let me search for new files who eventually it appers im tryng to loop the program but stop

Comment: Sorry, I can't quite follow…

Comment: i have a program that move files in to directory constantly, whit this code i read the names of the files and delete it, i need its to run the code until no files in the directory and continue runing  i think is whit a loop but when i put a loop in the code it stop

Comment: Let me suggest to use the Windows Task Scheduler to periodically run the script…

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should help:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1* delims=_." %%i in ('dir /b /s /a-d "*_*_*.mp4"2^>nul ^| findstr.exe /ILV "\\outdir\\"') do (
    set "var=%%j"
    for /f "tokens=2,* delims=_." %%a in ("%%j") do echo !var:_%%b=!
)
```

Keep in mind that using `delims` will also split on consecutive characters like double underscore. for those you need to predetermine which has double underscore and let the script add it for you.

Comment: tnks but, still add a number in some of the prints but is close

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
for %%a in (
20201323223_vendo.perfil01_17872513294967257_1601950878_live.mp4
20201323223__vvcastrillon_12_17949951031375250_1601939874_live.mp4
2020323123_yessromero.g_17849208194340047_1601945592_live.mp4
2020323223_ziizii_08_17979840166310477_1601929868_live.mp4
) do  set "filename=%%a" &call :process&echo --------------------------------------
GOTO :EOF

:process
echo stage 1 %filename%
:: step 1 : delete all characters up to and including the first underscore
set "filename=%filename:*_=%"
echo stage 2 %filename%
:: step 2 : find all numeric strings of length 4 or more in remainder
call :strsgt4 %filename:_= %
:: step 3 : replace each numeric string of length 4 or more + preceding underscore with "/" (invalid filename character)
echo stage 3 %filename%
:proc3lp
if "%zapstrings%" neq " " for %%v in (%zapstrings%) do call set "filename=%%filename:_%%v=/%%"&call set "zapstrings=%%zapstrings: %%v=%%"&goto proc3lp 
echo stage 4 %filename%
:: step 5 : Remove all charactersincluding and after the first "/"
for /f "delims=/" %%v in ("%filename%") do echo result %%v
goto :eof

:strsgt4
set "zapstrings= "
:strsgt4loop
set "test=%1"
if not defined test goto :eof
set "test=%test:~4%"
if defined test call :isnum %test%&if not defined notnumber set "zapstrings=%zapstrings% %1"
shift
goto strsgt4loop

:: Determine whether %1 is purely numeric
:isnum
SET "notnumber=9%~1"
FOR /l %%z IN (0,1,9) DO CALL SET "notnumber=%%notnumber:%%z=%%"
GOTO :eof
```

Really a question of working out what your rules are.

I decided that your rules were: string after the first underscore, until before the first subsequent underscore that precedes a numeric string or length greater than 3

The `%%a` loop simply submits a sequence of sample strings to `:process`

The inline comments should explain the remainder.